# How to remove the decimal point using applescript?

Tags: excel, macos, automation, applescript

Hi i'm writing a script to access the excel cells but instead of accessing the cell "A22" it is trying to access "A22.0" which leads to error.

Example:

set test to 20

set aCell to "A"& test

set myData to value of range "A2:aCell" of workshett "sheet1" of workbook "workbook"

In the above example the instead of accessing "A2:A20" it is trying to access "A2:A20.0" which leads to error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By inserting the variable **aCell** into a string like "A2:aCell", you are inserting into the string not the **value** of the variable, but its **name**. The result of such an operation will not be "A2:A20" but the same "A2:aCell". Because **AppleScript doesn't replace a variable's name with its value within a string**..

Instead, you need to perform a concatenation operation ("A2" & aCell). As soon as AppleScript sees the **& operator**, it understands that it needs to extract the value of the variable, and not use its name.

```
set test to 20

set aCell to "A" & test

("A2:" & aCell) --> "A2:A20"

set myData to value of range ("A2:" & aCell) of worksheet "sheet1" of workbook "workbook"
```

Answer (score -1):

You are coercing (putting together) a number and a string. "A" is a string, but 20 is a number, hence the '.0'. To fix this, you can make test a string by surrounding the 20 with quotes:

```
set test to "20"
```

If you want to replace the 20 with a number variable, you can convert it into a string value with:

```
set test to number_variable as string
```

Comment: Here the problem is not at all the need to coerce a number into a string. Because in the operation **set aCell to "A" & 20**, the left operand is a string, and as a result of this, AppleScript itself coerces where it needs to, implicitly.